# How to split a file content using Golang without duplicating the usage of RAM

Tags: go

With the code below I can open a file and split its content at each chat `|`. However my filesize if huge and I need to optimize memory usage. If you take a close look in the code below, every time I am having to duplicate the memory usage just to assign the value to another variable (of another type).

How can I split a file content at a specific char with the least amount of unnecessary memory?

```
temp3292,_ := ioutil.ReadFile("C:\\file.txt");
temp1114 := string(temp3292);
//Cleaning memory.
temp3292 = nil;
temp5078 := strings.Split(strings.Trim(temp1114,"|"),"|");
//Cleaning memory again.
temp1114 = "";

my_array := map[string]bool{};

for _,valor67 := range temp5078 {

    my_array[valor67] = true;

}

//Again, cleaning memory again.
temp5078 = nil;
```

Comment: Strings are more convenient but less efficient. If you're looking for efficiency, you need to stick with `[]byte`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicating data in memory, stay in byte slices and just re-slice them:

```
fileContent,_ := ioutil.ReadFile("C:\\file.txt");
sepPos := bytes.Index(fileContent, []byte('|'));
firstHalf := fileContent[:sepPos]
secondHalf := fileCOntent[sepPos+1:]
```

You'll find useful helpers in the [`bytes` package](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/) and some fundamentals [on the Go blog](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro).